# More efficient way to find max of multiple like-objects in array JS?

Tags: javascript

Is there an array method (or any other way really) to group objects within an array by a property and sum by another. Then return the max?

```js
let array = [
    {ticker:'AAPL',val:400},
    {ticker:'IBM',val:200},
    {ticker:'AAPL',val:500},
    {ticker:'SBUX',val:800},
]

let obj = {}

array.forEach( h => {
    obj[h.ticker] = obj[h.ticker] || 0;
    obj[h.ticker] += h.val
})

let temp = Object.keys( obj ).map(function ( key ) { return obj[key] }); 

console.log(Math.max(...temp)) // returns 900
```

Comment: What's the problem with your current approach? SO is not for suggestions if you don't have a tangible problem. It seems like you are pre-optimizing.

Comment: *"or any other way really"*: you provided one. But you can shorten a bit: `Math.max(...Object.values(obj))`.

Comment: One way is to have an object that you add items to, and when an item is added, update the sum and max properties of that object.

Comment: If you have working code and you want input on formatting, efficiency, etc, the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the place.

Comment: Was trying to use the reduce method, but no luck. I don't think that works here. The script will be running on a large dataset, so was just looking to possibly reduce steps. Thanks for the feedback, will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to modify it to use `reduce` instead of `forEach`, you can do:

```js
let obj = array.reduce((a,b) => ({...a, [b.ticker]: (a[b.ticker] || 0) + b.val}), {});
```